# How to run a clang's AST using llvm

Tags: clang, llvm, lldb

I have using function ParserAST() to get a AST ,but I don't know how to display the ast on my console(i am using vs 2017). And how can i using llvm to run the ast and get the information about the var value.

Answer (score 0):

Try `clang -Xclang -ast-dump -fsyntax-only test.c`, if want to print AST.

And,
You cannot run your own AST on llvm. Instead, see LLVM-JIT.